# Deploying tabular model to Azure Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

During deploying tabular model to Azure Analysis Services I get:

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source and the gateway is not installed for the server x.

[image]

> Technical Details:
>
> On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source and the
>   gateway is not installed for the server x.

The output shows:

[image]

The build is succeed.

I also created Gateway on this server and added used source (SQL Server).

Tables are deployed, but without any data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had PowerBI Gateway, not Azure Gateway.

After changing it, deployment succeed.